# Reports in XamarinForms(Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms

As i am working for my bachelor degree, one of the requirements is to be able to see some reports (like SSRS or like Crystal Reports) in the application. As the title says i am doing it in XamarinForms cross-platform ( for the moment if i am able to view them in android and wpf will be great ).

I searched and i didn't find something specific and i don't know what to do.

I'm getting my data from an RESTful API in .NET Core 2.1, that is published on azure cloud, as well with my Database. I tried to make a pdf in the API and just return it so i can view it in the XamarinForms but i have some doubts about this method.

I have to specify that the Azure Cloud account is not mine and i don't know how to use all the options that are listed on their service.

Is there a way of doing it clean and nice? If yes can you explain brief the workflow and how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Off topic IMO but server side generated PDF is perfectly fine for a REST API. You may also consider an HTML view (rendered server side and displayed client side) which is probably better when viewing with small screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Pdf is the best options, this works perfectly on xamarin form use PDFSharp or make use of IO Stream Class

```
 public string SaveFiles(PDFFormatModel pd)
    {

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell Name"));
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.AddCell("Cell 1 ");
        table.AddCell("Cell 1 Value");
        table.AddCell("Cell 2 ");
        table.AddCell("Cell 2 Value");


        var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        string root = null;
        if (Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageEmulated)
        {
            root = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
        }
        else
            root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        Java.IO.File myDir = new Java.IO.File(root + "/MAMN");
        myDir.Mkdir();

        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, pd.FileName);
        if (file.Exists()) file.Delete();
        using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            FileOutputStream outs = new FileOutputStream(file);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.Add(table);

            pdfDoc.Close();
            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(root, pd.FileName);            
            outs.Write(bytes);
            outs.Flush();
            outs.Close();
            if (file.Exists())
            {
                Android.Net.Uri path = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
                string extension = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString());
                string mimeType = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                intent.SetDataAndType(path, mimeType);
                Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose App"));
            }             
                return filePath;

        }       
    }
```

Also if you need to represent the data in charts or graphs go for MicroCharts or Syncfusion

Comment: can you tell me about the references you use? because i get tons of errors. do you have a special class for some objects? what version of xamarin forms do you use ?

Comment: Xam.iTextSharpLGPL  Use this reference, also there are many samples available on internet

Comment: I know it passed like 2 years but how i finished the problem is by using Syncfusion free version for students. I will accept this answer as the solution.